# Redmine docker image, can't save changes on local db

Tags: mysql, docker, redmine

i don't understand a situation of my a docker image of redmine

```
    docker-compose version 1.27.4, build 40524192
```

---

```
    Redmine yml: 
version: '3.0'
    services:
      redmine:
        image: redmine:4.1
        ports:
          - 8080:3000
        environment:
          REDMINE_DB_MYSQL: *internal ip of my machine*
          REDMINE_DB_PORT: 3306
          REDMINE_DB_DATABASE: *correct_db*
          REDMINE_DB_USERNAME: *user*
          REDMINE_DB_PASSWORD: *password*
        volumes:
          - /var/lib/some-redmine/files:/usr/src/redmine/files
          - /var/lib/some-redmine/plugins:/usr/src/redmine/plugins
          - /var/lib/some-redmine/vendor/plugins:/usr/src/redmine/vendor/plugins
          - /var/lib/some-redmine/public/themes:/usr/src/redmine/public/themes
```

---

```
Local Mysql of the machine: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.27-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

For internal reason i need to user the mysql of the local machine, for this reason i don't have a second image for db, and i user the internal ip of the machine (192.168.....).

The user "user" have all permission on the "correct_DB".

when i start the image with "docker-compose - f /path -d" all works fine, i can use my redmine with the correct db, so i can enter with my admin user and change all i want...**but the strange thing is this:**
If i modify something (create a user, change a password ecc..) the modification does not give me errors, but if i wat a couple of hours (the session https expire) and i re-login into my new redmine, everything is back as before the changes!.

The logs don't help me...
Now i try to enter in my local mysql and search the tables for see if there are the  modifications

Update:
I've try to create a new user, i entered inside mysql and i see the new users (inside the table "users") but after 20 minutes, the session https is expired and the users inside my mysql is disappeared..

thanks for any respons

P.s. if i create a new ticket with an attachment  can  see him in the correct folder: - /var/lib/some-redmine/files:/usr/src/redmine/files

Comment: do your redmine container logs show successful connections to the database or specific errors? Are you modifying redmine users (as opposed to database users)? Are these tables innodb and running in a transaction which isn't being commited?

Comment: my docker-image logs don't have anythng of usefull, only the web-calls (esample:172.29.0.1 - - [30/Jun/2021:08:37:20 UTC] "GET /serviceworker.js HTTP/1.1" 404 459
https://s******/serviceworker.js -> /serviceworker.js)
i try to modify a existed user, and create new one (result is the same)
for the last question, i'm pretty sure but yes